# Test for a dichotomous variable of the same group

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am quite new to statistics and I am messing myself a bit. Imagine I have a group of 1000 people aged under 18 and 700 smoke and 300 do not (70% and 30%, respectively). Is there a test to see if that is significantly different from 50%. I think there is not as they are from the same group of people... but just in case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The search term you are looking for is "binomial test".

Comment: Thank you very much! Is there a similar one for a three categorical variable?

Comment: Yes, search for chi-squared test. But really if your journey in statistics is just starting you need to do a bit more learning before looking at real data as all the methods rest on assumptions which you need to learn about.

Comment: I agree emphatically with @mdewey's second comment. Take some courses in statistics, preferably at a university. At a very, very minimum, read some good books. One outstanding introduction to statistics is called *Statistics* by Freedman, Pisani, and Purves.